# connect any mobile app to odoo backend apps

Tags: odoo-13

For example mobile commerce app need to link to sales back end and accounting
(mobile app native)
is rest api needed in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Odoo provides a RPC calls for all of this methods, you can use XML-RPC or JSON-RPC. If you have for example a react-native mobile app, I recommend the implementation of a proxy like software that gets all request from the mobile and translate to Odoo RPC and vice versa. Check this software that can help you.

https://github.com/renelhs/react-native-odoo-proxy